# How to limit the characters of featured article titles

Tags: joomla2.5

I need to have the article title in the homepage (featured articles) only in one line.
So, it is needed that the titles do not exceed 26 characters. The remaining characters would be stripped out and replaced by ...

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FooThis is something that is achieved with a plugin. The following should do the job - pls. zip these files and install using extension mgr.

foo.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension type="plugin" version="1.6" method="upgrade" group="content">
<name>Content - foo</name>
<creationDate>2013-05-30</creationDate>
<version>1.0</version>
<releaseDate>2013-06-07 07:08:00</releaseDate>
<releaseType>First public release!</releaseType>
<author>Michael Baas</author>
<authorEmail>mb@mbaas.de</authorEmail>
<authorUrl>mbaas.de</authorUrl>
<copyright>(c) 2013 Michael Baas</copyright>
<description>Limit length of featured article-titles - demo</description>
<files>
<filename plugin="foo">foo.php</filename>
</files>
</extension>
```

foo.php

```
<?php
    class plgContentFoo extends JPlugin
        {
        public function onContentPrepare($context,$article,$params,$limitstart)
        {

        $view = JRequest::getCmd( 'view');
        // echo "view=$view";
        $fp = $in_array($view,array("Frontpagecategory","addmore"));

            if ($fp && 26<strlen($article->title)) {
                $article->title = trim(substr($article->title,0,23)) . "...";
                return true;
            }
        }


    }

?>
```

If it does not work for you, it might be that you have a different view on your frontpage. In that case pls. remove the comments from "// echo "view=$view";" and replace "addmore" in the following line with the result that is shown when you view the frontpage. (But careful: "Frontpagearticle" means you are viewing an individual article from the frontpage, I assume in that case you would not want the trimming...)

Also the "common" method of detecting whether or not the user is viewing the frontpage is described here: http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_determine_if_the_user_is_viewing_the_front_page   BUT the problem with the approach is that also viewing a single article that was featured on fp would cause these statements to return "TRUE" which I think is wrong, because the users is not viewing **the** frontpage then...

Yet, having said that, it could be that my code might also fail in a few cases and would need to be combined with the method from the article I linked to (checking the menu)...

Comment: Thank you. I'll use the plugin in joomla 2.5. I tried it in a localhost and it does not work - returns the message:

`class plgContentFoo extends JPlugin { public function onContentPrepare($context,$article,$params,$limitstart) { if ($article->frontpage) { $article->title = trim(substr($article->title,0,26)); return true; } } } ?> `

Any idea?

Comment: Yeah, sorry - the first line in foo.php was missing, I fixed that in the code above...

Comment: Fixed yet another bug (frontpage -> featured)

Comment: Another challenge :)
Is it possible to add '...' when the title is trimmed? (note: only when the title is trimmed and not in all titles in the frontpage)

Comment: No words to express my gratitude!!! That was absolutely what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: ooops! The title gets trimmed also in the full view of the article, not only in the frontpage... any idea to prevent this?

Comment: That's fascinating - it dawned on me that this would not be restricted to the frontpage just one hour ago! :((  Surely this is also possible, I'll have a look!

Comment: Ok, I hope I fixed that too :)

Comment: I don't know why but it returns a fatal error: Fatal error: Function name must be a string in /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/plugins/content/foo/foo.php on line 1

Answer (score 0):

Just substring to ensure sufficient length. I don't know Joomla but the C# equivalent would be:

```
private string FormatForTitle(string input)
{
    if (input.Length <= 26)
    {
        return input;
    }

    // Trim
    return input.Substring(0, 23) + "...";
}
```

Should not be hard to port to PHP.

Comment: That's the idea but I need to implement it in the PHP file for the featured articles in the homepage of a joomla site.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(".PopularPosts .post-title a").each(function(){
    if($(this).text().length>10)
    {$(this).text($(this).text().substr(0, 10)+'...');}
});    
//]]>
</script>
```